# Number of regulators required for specify the total state of genes

Tags: gene-expression, gene-regulation, biological-networks

My course notes make the following claim:

If the regulation of each gene could include all transcription regulators
available, then in principle the total state of all genes could be specified with only $log_2(N)$ regulators.

It then gives this explanation:

To see this, imagine that one had 10 regulators that can be on or off. Then one can, in principle, specify $2^{10}$
different states, and thus specify all possible states for up to N = $2^{10}$ genes.

I don't understand the explanation given. For n genes, each of which can be turned on or off, there should be $2^{n}$ states. This would then mean N regulators would be required to regulate N genes.

Could anyone explain why this is incorrect?

Comment: Not sure what this means. what does "total state of all genes could be specified" mean? "Specified" like once we observe log2(N) regulators as on/off we can make a good guess about the state of any given gene, or we can make a statement about some overall state of the network, or something? Or like if we were god we could completely control the network by turning on/off only log2(N) regulators? What is "total state"?

Comment: @MaximilianPress I think it means that all the possible states for N genes could be specified using log2(N) regulators.

Comment: Have you asked your course instructor?

Comment: @jore1 I'm still not sure what a state is, or what it means for regulators to specify states for genes. In what context? why? I suspect that this is a description of a mathematical/graphical model of gene regulation, but the terms and structure of the model are not specified in your question, so it's hard for me to evaluate standalone statements about the behavior of the model.